# Url Pattern lost while using RedirectToAction method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am new in MVC, please review the following case:

Rule in global.asax;

```
routes.MapRoute(
"MonographContent", // Route name
"{controller}/{action}/{monographRevisionId}/{monographId}/{monographName}", // URL with parameters
new { controller = "Monographs", action = "MonographContent", monographRevisionId = String.Empty, monographId = String.Empty, monographName = String.Empty });
```

My Controller;

```
public ActionResult MonographContent(string monographRevisionId, string monographId, string monographName)
{
  return View();
}
```

Following url works fine;

http://localhost/Monographs/MonographContent/v3/191b7a7e-a1bc-4602-b2bd-ac1193e07d25/MyMonograph

But when I redirects to the same action method through another action method it converts into QueryString

Action Method

```
public ActionResult Archive(string monographRevisionId, string monographId, string monographName)
{
return RedirectToAction("MonographContent", new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Monographs", action = "MonographContent", monographRevisionId = String.Empty, monographId = String.Empty, monographName = String.Empty }));
}
```

http://localhost/Monographs/MonographContent?monographRevisionId=v3&monographId=191b7a7e-a1bc-4602-b2bd-ac1193e07d25&monographName=MyMonograph

Can anyone help me how to fix it to preserve the url pattern.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try to redirect directly by route:

```
this.RedirectToRoute("MonographContent", new { monographRevisionId = String.Empty, monographId = String.Empty, monographName = String.Empty })});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should simply issue a normal `Redirect()` call:

```
return Redirect("/Monographs/MonographContent/");
```

Particularly based on the RouteValueDictionary you provided in your example.